# Regex with the following conditions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to understand how regex works by matching a regex for the following conditions:

1. string must start with one or more alphanumeric characters.
2. string must be followed by a '@' sign
3. string must be followed by the string 'asa' immediately after  the '@'
4. string must be followed by a string containing one or more 0's and/or 1's
5. string must be followed by another @
6. string must be followed by a collection of one or more special characters and/or numbers, no letters
7. string must end with 'abc'

I am around step 4 and now I am stuck, was wondering if someone can provide some suggestions:

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+@+[asa]+[01]/";
$subject = "abcB123Ccac@asa01";
echo preg_match($pattern,$subject) ? 'MATCH' : 'NO MATCH';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+@asa[01]+@[^A-Za-z]+abc$
```

Code would be,

```
$pattern = "~^[A-Za-z0-9]+@asa[01]+@[^A-Za-z]+abc$~";
$subject = "abcB123Ccac@asa01";
echo preg_match($pattern,$subject) ? 'MATCH' : 'NO MATCH';
```

1. string must start with one or more alphanumeric characters.

   ```
   ^[A-Za-z0-9]+
   ```
2. string must be followed by a '@' sign

   ```
   @
   ```
3. string must be followed by the string 'asa' immediately after  the '@'

   ```
   asa
   ```
4. string must be followed by a string containing one or more 0's and/or 1's

   ```
   [01]+
   ```
5. string must be followed by another @

   ```
   @
   ```
6. string must be followed by a collection of one or more special characters and/or numbers, no letters (Excluding letters)

   ```
   [^A-Za-z]+
   ```
7. string must end with 'abc'

   ```
   abc$
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Avinash Raj, Can you please explain the thought process for each step, which is what I am most interested in :)

Comment: +1, thank you! How does `_W` match all special characters in the last step ? Also, what does the beginning and ending `~` do ?

Comment: it's a typo . It's `\W` and `~` is a php regex delimiter. `\W` matches all the non-word characters.

Comment: Still, I don't understand what `_\W` has to do with matching all special characters ? With matching letters we have `a-z`, numbers `0-9`, and special characters seems totally different :)

Comment: i assume you mean the special characters as `_` plus all the non-word characters (except `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `_`)

Comment: No, for step 6, by special characters, I mean excluding letters a-z and A-Z, only symbols and numbers